# Keyboard access in the C# project settings editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

Does anyone know how to switch between the major tabs/pages in Visual Studio's C# project settings editor, using only the keyboard? I'm talking about the things along the left side that are labeled Application, Build, Debug, Resources, Settings, etc. It works fine to Tab between the controls on the currently selected page, but I haven't figured out how to switch between pages, and I like to avoid leaving the keyboard as much as possible.

The page that I most frequently want to access is the Debug page, so a shortcut that takes me directly to that page would be fine even if there wasn't a general method. I tried the Project.StartOptions command, but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Down</kbd> will navigate between those tabs/pages.

Comment: Awesome! Stack Overflow to the rescue.